# Ext:BooleanColumn,when editing ,it shows true or false value

Tags: ext.net

I have a grid and there is ext:BooleanColumn inside it,and I put a combobox for editing boolen colum.everything works fine ,except of this one .when I click boolen colum to edit,it shows false or true inside it,
I added a image what I trying to say.
how I can avoid this .thank you[image]

and here is the my code :

```
<ext:BooleanColumn ID="BooleanColumn1" runat="server" DataIndex="BorcOdendimi" TrueText="odendi" Text="ödenme durumu"
              FalseText="odenmedi" >
              <Editor>
      <ext:ComboBox  runat="server"  Text="odendi durumu" Editable="false">

        <Items>
 <ext:ListItem Text="Odendi" Value="1" />
 <ext:ListItem Text="Odenmedi" Value="0" />
        </Items>
     </ext:ComboBox>
  </Editor>
   </ext:BooleanColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it working the Values of the ComboBox's Items should match the values of a BooleanColumn. Currently, true/false (BooleanColumn's values) doesn't match 1/0 (ComboBox Items' values).

You can replace the existing ComboBox's Items with:

```
<ext:ListItem Text="Odendi" Value="true" Mode="Raw" />
<ext:ListItem Text="Odenmedi" Value="false" Mode="Raw" />
```

Answered in [the Ext.NET forums thread](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?25394#post112125).